# tinymce editor content value not showing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i will used tinymce html editor

my problem is when editor position change that time editor will null

[image]

see image when down arrow click editor position not change but content null

i can used javascript code  for up arrow and down arrow code

```
$("body").on("click", ".upclass", function() {
     var click=this.id;



     console.log(click);    
 $('.div'+click+':parent').insertBefore($('.div'+click+':parent').prev());
});

 $("body").on("click", ".downclass", function() {

    var downclick=this.id;



    var demo=$('.div'+downclick+':parent');
     $(demo).insertAfter($(demo).next());
});
```

how to do this position change textarea id give dynamically means id is not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are running into is tied to how `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` manipulate the DOM.  If you remove the underlying `<textarea>` from the DOM you break its connection to TinyMCE.  When you re-insert the `<textarea>` into the DOM its a "new" `<textarea>` and TinyMCE is no longer connected to the `<textarea>`.

To successfully move the `<textarea>` you need to do 3 things...

1. Call `triggerSave()` to update the underlying `<textarea>` with the current value of TinyMCE.  TinyMCE does not keep the `<textarea>` in sync as you type - this would be a lot of overhead for the editor so it does not do this as you type.  `triggerSave()` pushes the current content of the editor back into the `<textarea>`.  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave
2. Use the `remove()` method to remove TinyMCE from the `<textarea>` you are about to move.  Remove will properly "disconnect" TinyMCE from the `<textarea>`.  You can target a specific instance of TinyMCE by using the id of the underlying `<textarea>`:  `tinymce.remove('#idoftextarea');`
3. After you move the `<textarea>` reinitialize TinyMCE on that `<textarea>`.  You can use `tinymce.init({});` just as you did when you first loaded the page to reload TinyMCE onto the `<textarea>`.

If you follow these steps the content should still appear properly after you move the `<textarea>` within the DOM.

Comment: Thanks  i have try this but not take any sucesss :(  if you have any demo so please kindly share with me :)

Comment: Why don't you use JS Fiddle or CodePen to build out an example of what you are doing ... then myself or others can help you tweak your code.

Comment: markitup editor you know i want one help in that my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978603/markitup-editor-how-content-value-write-html-view